# Windows 8.1 drag from top to down makes desktop small and take only half the screen

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, modern-ui

I know the title is silly, but I really don't know how to describe it.
So when I am on the desktop, and I try to make a selection by holding left click, and I do it from the top, it makes the desktop small, and then it only takes half the screen, a black line at center appears, and the other half is empty. So you have to click that line to dissapear...

How do I disable this? Or any other Metro tools/gestures for that matter, I want them all disabled (even if having to install 3rd party software)

EDIT: Pictures
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this issue? We can't quite understand the issue unless we can see precisely what's going on.

Comment: there, edited the question

Comment: take the mouse pointer on the black border in the middle of the screen, click on it, hold the click and move it to the right side.

Comment: or double-click the black bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this behaviour can unfortunately not be disabled on Windows 8.1. It is part of Microsoft's "Modern UI" and core to 8.1. It does suck, but note that dragging is only triggered if the mouse is within a couple of pixels of the top of the screen. If you find you've accidentally triggered dragging the entire desktop, just release the mouse and try again. Aim slightly lower next time.